# Flexigrid implementation of css change dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

i have problem with implementation of change background color of one row in Flexigrid table when I do some action in that table.

I have table defined like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#newTable").flexigrid({
        url: 'agendaTipoAppuntamentoInitJson.do',
        dataType: 'json',
        colModel : [
            {display: 'ID',                 name : 'idTipoAppuntamento', width : 40, sortable : false, align: 'center', hide: true},
            {display: 'Codice',             name : 'codice', width : 60, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Descrizione',        name : 'descrizione', width : 130, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Descr. breve',       name : 'descrBreve', width : 80, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Colore',             name : 'colore', width : 80, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'ID Struttura',       name : 'idStruttura', width : 60, sortable : false, align: 'left', hide: true},
            {display: 'Descr. Struttura',   name : 'descrizioneStruttura', width : 150, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'ID Spec',            name : 'idSpecializzazione', width : 60, sortable : false, align: 'left', hide: true},
            {display: 'Descr. Spec',        name : 'descrizioneSpecializzazione', width : 150, sortable : false, align: 'left'}
            ],
        usepager: true,
        title: 'Gestione tipi appuntamento',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 950,
        height: 370,
        singleSelect: true,
        click: editMe
    }); 


});
```

and have JQuery dialog:

```
$(function() {

        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog({
             open : function(event, ui) { 
                  originalContent = $("#newDialog-form").html();
                  $('#coloreIns').simpleColorPicker({ showEffect: 'fade', hideEffect: 'slide' });
               },
               close : function(event, ui) {
                  $("#newDialog-form").html(originalContent);
               },
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,

            buttons: {
                Salva: function() {

                     $.ajax({

                            url: 'agendaTipoAppuntamentoSaveJson.do',

                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: $("#newDialogForm").serialize(),
                            success: function(result) {
                                if (result.esito!='OK') {
                                    alert(result.esito + ' ' + result.message);  
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#newTable").flexReload();
                                    $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog( 'close' );

                                }
                            },
                            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
                        }  
                        });



                },
                Annula : function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }

            }});

        $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog({ closeText: ''  });

    });
```

I need some JavaSript function to channge css of row that is inserted with Salva function in dialog box.

Don't understand how to do it in Flexigrid.